# How to add new line in a Bootstrap button using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap how do I make the subtitle of the button break to a new line using CSS.

My Button consist of the button text, and a button subtitle. the button subtitle being in the small tag.

I dont want to use the html BR, I have been trying to do this in CSS.

## HTML using the BR

```
<a id="option_button" class="btn btn-success" >Button Text<br/><small>This is the sub-title of the button</small></a>
```

## HTML using the CSS

```
<a id="option_button" class="btn btn-success" >Button Text<small>This is the sub-title of the button</small></a>
```

## CSS

```
#option_button small {
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to:

```
#option_button small {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked, I tried it out on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smcd/qLqfsd1c/

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to add [**`white-space: pre`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the parent element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4dLktkq/)

In doing so, the new line in your HTML will be respected.

> [**MDN - `white-space: pre`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

```css
#option_button {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a id="option_button" class="btn btn-success">Button Text
    <small>This is the sub-title of the button</small>
</a>
```

---

Of course, you could also make the `small` element `block` level, too.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cmzso99/)

```
#option_button small {
    display: block;
}
```

---

Another option is to use a pseudo-element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0fg6uo3u/)

```
#option_button small:before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Also a good answer, Trevers answer was  quicker to implement (by 1 line :)) in my solution but after looking the sample output I can now see whats happening. When using pre I was assuming the typeface was going to be mono-spaced